# Regex: Match a fixed phrase and the following words/characters and stop at a certain word (AND)

Tags: java, regex

Here is the sample data from a JBehave story that I want to extract from:

```
And we validate that the following occurrences for event 123456 and source PLAYER are saved in Database:
| PLAYER | GAME     | 
| 1      | FOOTBALL |

And we validate that the following messages for event 123456 and source PLAYER are sent in Other Database:
```

**Using the fixed phrase:**

```
 And we validate that the following occurrences for event 123456 and source PLAYER are saved in Database:
```

I want to use that sentence as the starting point of my search and get everything up until the next word **And**

**Expected Output:**

```
And we validate that the following occurrences for event 123456 and source PLAYER are saved in Database:
| PLAYER | GAME     | 
| 1      | FOOTBALL |
```

I have tried the following expression:

`\w*:[^And]*`

However, I haven't figured out the part where I match using the fixed phrase.

Comment: Check your regular expression at https://regex101.com/, hint: `[^And]` does not do, what you think it does.

Comment: Something like `.*:(?s)(?:(?!\bAnd\b).)*`?

Comment: I think using "()" instead of "[]" can help you. see: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402416/regular-expression-to-match-a-word-or-its-prefix).

Comment: Or `.*:(?s).*?(?=\bAnd\b|$)`?

Comment: Have you tried https://regex101.com/r/FgM0SJ/1?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! It works now. I should have looked up using a negative look ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
.*:(?s).*?(?=\bAnd\b|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FgM0SJ/1)

**Details**

- `.*` - any amount of any chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `:` - a colon
- `(?s)` - now, all `.` to the right will match any chars including line break chars
- `.*?` - any amount of any chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\bAnd\b|$)` - a positive lookahead that ensures there is a whole word `And` or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.